# Can someone explain why my function is "out of scope"?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am writing a Binary Search Tree class, but am running into a strange issue. In my code below, I have a function that I have called `inorderHelper`. I also have a function that overloads the insertion operator (<<). I would like to call the `inorderHelper` function from inside of my insertion operator function, but am getting an error when I compile, stating that `inorderHelper` was not declared in scope.

```
void BinTree::inorderHelper(Node *startNode) const{
    if (startNode != nullptr){
        inorderHelper(startNode->left);
        cout << startNode->data;
        inorderHelper(startNode->right);
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BinTree& T){
    inorderHelper (T.root); //This is the line where I am told that `inorderHelper` is not declared in this scope.
}
```

I think that the problem might have to do with how I have defined my `inorderHelper` function. Because it is a private member function, my friend function (the insertion function) cannot call it. Is that correct of me to assume?

Comment: It looks like you've missed `T.` prior to invocation of non-static member function `inorderHelper`.

Comment: @user7860670 - as in, `T.inorderHelper(T.root);` ?

Comment: Non-static class methods must be called on a particular object. That object is defined either explicitly or implicitly. There is no implicit object in your case, so you have to be explicit `T.inorderHelper(T.root);`. In other words you are calling the `inorderhelper` method on the object referred to by `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator<< is outside your class. Since you have made this function as a friend, you will be able to use the private functions of "an object".
But in your code, you are not using an object of BinTree while calling the function "inorderHelper".

If you are trying to call the "inorderHelper" function of object "T", you have to call like T.inorderHelper(T.root).

Answer (score 2):

Unless your member function is defined as `static`, you cannot call member functions like that (even if its marked as a `friend`). Making it a `friend` only allows you to access its private and protected members, calling a member function stays the same.

So if what you want is to pass `BinTree::root` to `BinTree::inorderHelper()`, and it should be done to the `T` parameter, you could just do this,

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BinTree& T) {
    T.inorderHelper(T.root);
}
```

Note: Make sure you return a `std::ostream` reference or else it'll result in a compile error.